# how to select a element at specific location using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

is there a way to find the element at specific place when dealing with the same element occuring multiple time in jQuery

For example

```
<body>
    <p>Para first one</p>
    <p>Para first one</p>
    <p>Para first one</p>
</body>
```

If I want to directly access the second paragraph is there a direct way using Jquery?

Thank you

Comment: You can use .eq. In you case could be $( 'p' ).eq(1).

Comment: Or you can use $( 'p:eq(1)' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('p:nth-of-type(2)')` to select the second paragraph.

Comment: Suggested this rather than eq since the count starts at 1, not zero, so might be more readable. On the other hand, you may prefer indexes to start at zero if you're used to that as a developer, in which case you can use eq instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this

```
$("p").eq(1);
```

Keep in mind that `.eq()` is zero-based

Alternatively, you can do this in pure javascript, with this

```
var secondPara=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
```